# Mostrar soma de objetos em gráfico - Django/Python/Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, django, chartjs, gráfico

Como mostrar um gráfico com o somatório de objetos com Django/Python/SQlite?

Nesse caso temos 'caixas_internos' (eixo y) por 'equipes' (eixo x) que estão renderizando valores de 'caixas_interno' por cada inserção de 'equipe' no model PCdastro.

Exemplo gerado: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHptQcI4quZxTrh8RHHvn2wFmJPHO0QM/view

Como mostrar apenas a somatoria de 'caixas_interno' por 'equipe' no gráfico ao invés de mostrar todos os valores inseridos nesse model e ter repetido por ex:

no eixo x que representa 'equipe' repetir para cada valor de 'caixas_interno'. 1 -> 5; 1 -> 22; 1 -> 15.... ou seja, equipe 1 tem 5 caixas, equipe 1 tem 22 caixas, equipe 1 tem 15 caixas...

Como mostrar apenas, equipe 1 -> 42 caixas; equipe 2 -> 50 caixas; equipe 3 -> 30 caixas.... ?

views.py

```
def grafico_pcadastro(request):


queryset = PCadastro.objects.all().order_by('equipe')
equipes = [obj.equipe for obj in queryset]
caixas_internos = [obj.caixas_interno for obj in queryset]

context = {

    'equipes': json.dumps(equipes),
    'caixas_internos': json.dumps(caixas_internos),
}

return render(request, 'pintura/graficos.html', context)
```

graficos.html

```
<canvas id="grafico_pcadastroChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("grafico_pcadastroChart");
var equipes = JSON.parse('{{ equipes|safe }}');
var caixas_internos = JSON.parse('{{ caixas_internos|safe }}');
var grafico_pcadastroChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: equipes,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Caixas de Reboco',
        data: caixas_internos,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 0.5
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true

            }
        }]
     }
   }
});
</script>
```

models.py

```
class PCadastro(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    equipe = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    caixas_interno = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.equipe
```

Comment: teria como mostrar o conteúdo do json `equipes`? `equipe` é um foreignkey no modelo `PCadastro`?

Comment: @JonatasCD

O conteúdo de `equipes` é representado pela coluna `equipe` de `class PCadastro(models.Model):`. 

Não sei se entendi direito sobre oq seria o conteúdo do json `equipes`, mas no caso,  `equipes = [obj.equipe for obj in queryset]`.

models.py.

    class PCadastro(models.Model):
        equipe = models.CharField(max_length=2)    
        caixas_interno = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
        
        def __str__(self):
        return self.equipe

ou seja, `equipe` é um CharField no modelo `PCadastro`